# Where can I find .NET Framework class diagram?

Tags: .net, class-diagram, hierarchy

I just need a  file (picture, pdf or other type file for printing) of the framework structure.
It is very usefull while learning .Net framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[.NET Framework 3.5 Common Namespaces and Types Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7b645f3a-6d22-4548-a0d8-c2a27e1917f8&displaylang=en)

> November 2007 Edition The .NET
>   Framework 3.5 Common Namespaces and
>   Types Poster
>
> Overview
>   The .NET Framework 3.5 Common
>   Namespaces and Types Poster is
>   downloadable as XPS or PDF format.
>   There is also an XPS format file which
>   prints over 16 letter or A4 pages for
>   easy printing. Some assembly is
>   required if you choose this print
>   method.

Answer (score 3):

If you are bold and adventurous you can use [a tool I found on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoDiagrammer.aspx). Send the framework classes to it and, voila, after some crunching, grinding and groaning you should get a diagram from it.

Answer (score 2):

[Check this poster](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/10/29/net-framework-4-poster.aspx) and see if it helps.

[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/brada/WindowsLiveWriter/55ff37220b2c.NETFramework4Poster_67A1/PDC2008-NETFX4_thumb.png))</sub>

and Here is the [deep zoom version](http://brad_abrams.members.winisp.net/Projects/PDC2008/DotNet4Poster/DotNetFramework4PosterDeepZoom.htm).

Answer (score 1):

http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/a/3/4a3c7c55-84ab-4588-84a4-f96424a7d82d/NET_35_Namespaces_Poster_JAN08.pdf

Comment: Full resolution version: http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/a/3/4a3c7c55-84ab-4588-84a4-f96424a7d82d/NET_35_Namespaces_Poster_JAN08.pdf (PDF, 849 KB).

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at one (and several others) right behind me at the moment, apparently it comes with Visual C#/Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version of the .NET Framework, and it's a little unclear if you mean a map of each class or a map of all classes. Anyhow, here's for .NET 3.5:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/a/3/4a3c7c55-84ab-4588-84a4-f96424a7d82d/NET35_Namespaces_Poster_LORES.pdf