# Get .NET Class Hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, structure, hierarchy

I am trying to get all the objects in .NET Framework with their hierarchy order with their namespaces and put them into a tree structure or some sort for academic purposes in C#. I am trying to do this for a specific .NET framework platform. Is there a way to do such thing?

Request: List everything (classes, enums, structures etc.) under System.Threading namespace

**Result:**

**Constructors:**

- AbandonedMutexException
- Barrier
- Interlocked
- blah blah

**Structures:**

- AsyncFlowControl
- CancellationToken
- blah blah

**Delegates:**

- ContexCallback
- ThreadStart
- blah blah

**Enumerations:**

- blah blah

[Pretty much what I want is something like this. - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading(v=vs.110).aspx)

Many thanks.

---

**Edit: I am not asking for a code sample or someone to write the code for me - I just can't figure out where to start so I am looking for tips.**

Comment: This isn't a "do the work for me" site... Begin writing some code. You'll need to start from a collection of assemblies (`mscorlib`, `System` at minimum) and then "explore" them.

Comment: @xanatos I am aware of that, I just didn't know where to start.

Comment: Note that if you want to do it for a framework DIFFERENT from the one where you are running your app then it is more difficult... You'll need to use Mono.Cecil or similar libraries for loading the "other" .NET Framework .

Comment: You can check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157026/where-can-i-find-net-framework-class-diagram) for .NET 3.5 class poster. But if you want to create one your own, you need to iterate over all classes.

Comment: why do you need do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone (Groo) has alread given the "theoretical" reply about how you should do it, but note that there are at least two strong caveats:

- any Microsoft assembly could contain a `System.Threading` class (and technically **any** assembly could contain it, even yours, but it is bad etiquette to do it)
- if you want to explore a "base" assembly (*mscorlib*, *System*, ...) from a different version of .NET than the one you are running from then you'll need Mono.Cecil or similar library, because with Reflection you can't load a different version of a base assembly than the one you are running)

And now some very simple code:

```
var assemblyNames = new[]
{
    "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
    "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
    "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
};

var nss = new[]
{
    "System.Threading"
};


// Begin real code

var assemblies = Array.ConvertAll(assemblyNames, Assembly.Load);
var nss2 = Array.ConvertAll(nss, x => x + ".");

var types = assemblies.SelectMany(x => x.ExportedTypes).Where(x => nss2.Any(y => x.FullName.StartsWith(y))).ToArray();

// The Delegate check is taken from http://mikehadlow.blogspot.it/2010/03/how-to-tell-if-type-is-delegate.html
var classes = types.Where(x => x.IsClass && !typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(x)).ToArray();
var structs = types.Where(x => x.IsValueType && !x.IsEnum).ToArray();
var enums = types.Where(x => x.IsEnum).ToArray();
var delegates = types.Where(x => x.IsClass && typeof(Delegate).IsAssignableFrom(x)).ToArray();

// There is a DeclaringType property to see what Type is declaring them
var constructors = types.SelectMany(x => x.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some guidelines on how to get started:

1. You will need to use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx), i.e. the classes from the `System.Reflection` namespaces (`Assembly`, `ConstructorInfo`, `PropertyInfo`, and similar). As stated on MSDN:

   > The classes in the `System.Reflection` namespace, together with `System.Type`, enable you to **obtain information** about loaded assemblies and the types defined within them, such as classes, interfaces, and value types. You can also use reflection to **create type instances** at run time, and to **invoke and access them**.
2. Start by getting an instance of the `Assembly` class. You can either pass a type from the assembly you want to access (any type, like `System.Threading.Barrier` for example) and use `Assembly.GetAssembly`:

   ```
   var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Threading.Barrier));
   ```

   Or, if you're going to iterate through a folder of .dll files, you can use use `Assembly.LoadFrom`:

   ```
   var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("path-to-System.Threading.dll");
   ```
3. Once you have the assembly instance, you will want to iterate through the types and do further reflection upon them:

   ```
   foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
   {
       var constructors = type.GetConstructors();
       var fields = type.GetFields();
       var properties = type.GetProperties();
       ...
   }
   ```
4. The `Type` class, apart from these methods, also contains various properties which allow you to see if the specified type is a `class` or a `struct` (`Type.IsValueType`, `Type.IsInterface`, `Type.IsAbstract`, etc.), see if one type inherits or implement a different one (`Type.IsAssignableFrom(otherType)`, `Type.GetInterfaces`), and similar things.

Comment: I don't know for the given namespace, but *any DLL might define objects in any namespace. So for complete coverage, iteration through GAC may be necessary, depending on OP's specs.

Comment: @devio That is a problem in itself :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you can [get hold of the corresponding XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694986/net-framework-documentation-location) for the framework you're interested in, you might find it easier to transform that than to extract this information directly from the code.